# CursorLoader Android. Как создать новый лоадер?

Tags: android, adapter, cursor, мобильные-приложения, cursoradaper

```
 **protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all__lists);
        db = new DB(this);
        db.open();


        // формируем столбцы сопоставления
        String[] from = new String[] { "text_task", "compile_time" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textTask, R.id.textView_time };

        // создааем адаптер и настраиваем список
        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_task, null, from, to, 0  );
        lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MainListView);

        lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

        // создаем лоадер для чтения данных
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
    }
```

Сам класс имплементирует `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`.  В onCreate создается SimpleCursorAdapter.

```
В статичном классе 

static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

    DB db;

    public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
    }



    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor = GetBDData.getTodayList(db.mDB);
        return cursor;
    }

}
```

Вопрос: Как сделать новый запрос в базу и вывести в ListView результаты?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Обновить курсор вы хотите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно обновить ListView - создаете новый курсор, получаете данные.  У SimpleCursorAdapter есть метод, который позволяет обновить курсор -  scAdapter.changeAdapter(<новый курсор>); затем оповестить адаптер scAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();